# Jquery Mobile - Dynamically create a listview popup

Tags: listview, jquery-mobile, dynamic, popup

I want to display dynamically a listview in a popup using Jquery Mobile. When I write the HTML code I want in the listview it displays it well with the good css style. But when I generate the listview content using Javascript, the css style gets broken and I don't understand why.

Here is a JSFiddle of my problem, on the left the menu I want to obtain and on the right the menu I actually get : http://jsfiddle.net/c0enm7yo/

### HTML CODE :

```
<body>
    <div data-role="page" data-theme="c" id="projets">
        <div data-role="content" id="content">

            <div data-role="popup" id="menuIWant" data-theme="c" data-position-to="window" data-transition="slide">
                <ul data-role='listview' data-inset='true' data-icon='delete' style='min-width:210px;' id="menuIWantDivider">
                    <li data-role='list-divider'>Menu I Want</li>
                    <li><a href='#'>View details</a></li>
                    <li><a href='#'>Edit</a></li>
                    <li><a href='#'>Disable</a></li>
                    <li><a href='#'>Delete</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>

            <div data-role="popup" id="menuIGet" data-theme="c" data-position-to="window" data-transition="slide">
                <ul data-role='listview' data-inset='true' data-icon='delete' style='min-width:210px;' id="menuIGetDivider">
                    <li data-role='list-divider'>Menu I Get</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed" data-theme="f" data-tap-toggle="false" id="footer">
            <a href="#menuIWant" data-role="button" data-rel="popup" data-theme="c" id="menuIWantButton">Menu I want</a>  

            <a href="#menuIGet" data-role="button" data-rel="popup" data-theme="c" id="menuIGetButton">Menu I get</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

### Javascript code :

```
$(document).on('click', '#menuIGetButton', function(event)
{
    createDeleteProjectPopup();    
});

function createDeleteProjectPopup()
{
    $('<li>').append("<a href='#'>View details</a>").appendTo('#menuIGetDivider');
    $('<li>').append("<a href='#'>Edit</a>").appendTo('#menuIGetDivider');
    $('<li>').append("<a href='#'>Disable</a>").appendTo('#menuIGetDivider');
    $('<li>').append("<a href='#'>Delete</a>").appendTo('#menuIGetDivider');
}
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/c0enm7yo/1/

Comment: Simple and efficient, thanks Omar.